# API hit using form data in ionic2

Tags: ajax, rest, angular, ionic2

i want to hit api on form data  like when I am using  `let params ={"supplier_id": "538","verify":"1","item_id":itemId};`and api  is `this.aService.process('http://myapi.php', params)` then it is not working .When I am trying with

```
let _urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
    _urlParams.append('supplier_id', "538");
    _urlParams.append('verify', "1");
    _urlParams.append('item_id', itemId);
```

still it is not working and data is not showing in network . When I am using postman then if i am putting data on form-data then it is working and on raw it is not working .. What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

URLSearchParams != FormData

Try sending your data with

```
let input = {
  firstName: 'first name',
  (...)
};

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

this.http.post('https://angular2.apispark.net/v1/contacts/', $.param(input), { headers })
     .subscribe(...);
```